# Stack Overflow with no top bar with Ask

Tags: bug, asking-questions, user-experience, mobile-web

Once going to Stack Overflow on my Android using Chrome, it isn't straight forward to ask a question

[image: Stack]

Like in other communities

[image: PM Stack]

Can we add the same menu bar we see in blue (the color can be adjusted for the community, so SO could get like an orange one) with Questions, Tags, Users, Badges and Ask?

Comment: That looks like the "mobile site". I'm not sure that's getting much support love these days, and it's likely to be abandoned at some point. Why don't you use the responsive view (scroll down to the bottom and click on "full-site").

Comment: @yivi just got to know about that functionality now but I like to use the 'mobile site' style (only requires me to use Desktop mode for asking / answering questions).

Comment: What I mean, is that I'm not sure feature-requests that affect the "mobile site" are going to get much traction, when the efforts are currently poured on the responsive version that already is much better than the "mobile" view.

Comment: Oh... Then I have to adapt to the new way?

Comment: I think it would be for the better, yes. Maybe I'm wrong, but I don't see much value in the company maintaining a mobile view, when the new design is already a better answer to mobile needs.

Comment: The "full-site" forces too much my eyes with all the white. Do you know if I can make the colours darker also in this new version? (If yes, how?)

Comment: The responsive version supports "dark mode". The mobile version does not.

Comment: The mobile version was fine as it was. I'm speaking of the new version. Know about dark-mode available by Stack but not being able to find how to activate it only for mobile.

Comment: Dark mode is activated by profile, not by device. If you enable it in your profile, when you access the responsive version on your mobile device you'll get the dark mode enabled.

Comment: Is it my impression or in the profile, activity, etc. works as Desktop mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "mobile site" is largely unmaintained and it's likely to be abandoned at some point.

Instead, you should use the responsive view (scroll down to the bottom and click on "full-site") or use the site on a computer instead of a mobile device.

Comment: That's definitely not a solution... Often I don't have the computer with me...

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 Well, sorry. There's an option in the menu that you can use to do to the desktop site on mobile, but that's about it.

Comment: There's also "full site" in the bottom / footer of the mobile site, but in the profile / activity / and such views it's basically Chrome's Desktop mode

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 Yes, that's the responsive mode. It works much better, trust me.

Comment: It's still underdeveloped... Can start using just like yivi also suggests...